# Session cookies for multiple applications being stored on the same domain which leads to users logging out from other application

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, session, cookies, session-cookies

We have multiple applications being hosted on the same domain. For all apps, the session is stored in a cookie which is on the same domain as well.

Now if a user can access more than 1 app from the same browser, the he/she are being logged out of the other apps.

Can someone guide me on how we can design the apps in such a way that session information is not overridden across multiple apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this cookie is set from the server and we could control it from each application by configuring this extra property:
`server.servlet.session.cookie.name=Your_custome_name`

Cookie name is unique across all apps and across all environments.

This is tested and working.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'd like to mention that running multiple apps like this under the `one` domain should be discouraged since it could lead to security issues if one of these apps were compromised. One should use subdomains for this e.g., `<app1>.<domain>` then `<app2>.<domain>`

If you are still on this and want to achieve what you asked for, you must use the `paths` while setting cookies. As outlined on MDN web docs

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie

Comment: We can't change the domain as per design. Also, there's a way to set unique cookie name across all environments using Spring boot:
server.servlet.session.cookie.name=Your_custome_name